# my encryption program wont send result back

Tags: python, encryption, tkinter

i am working on an encryption program with tkinter for GUI 
the code dosent give me a result but it throws no errors
when it was displaying in console it worked but it seams like there is a problem with tkinter and i have no idea
here is the code

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

alphabit = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('encryption')
elable = Label(root, text="the word")
elable.grid(row=0, column=0)

e = Entry(root)
e.grid(row=1, column=0)

alable = Label(root, text="encryption level")
alable.grid(row=0, column=1)

a = Entry(root)
a.grid(row=1, column=1)


def encryption(m, x):
    encrypted = ''
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i] == ' ':
            encrypted += ' '
        for q in range(len(alphabit)):
            if m[i] == alphabit[q]:
                encrypted += alphabit[q + x]
    if len(encrypted) == len(m):
        print(encrypted)
        blable = Label(root, text=encrypted)
        blable.grid(row=3, column=0)


button = Button(root, text='encrypt', command=encryption(e.get(), a.get()))
button.grid(row=2, column=1)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

What do I changed: I called the method then I get the values. Used the instance of `tk` to perform `mainloop`and also changed `encrypted += alphabit[q + x]` because your trying to concatenate string with int and I didn't get it why so I removed the `m`.

```
import tkinter as tk

alphabit = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
            'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('encryption')
elable = Label(root, text="the word")
elable.grid(row=0, column=0)

e = Entry(root)
e.grid(row=1, column=0)

alable = Label(root, text="encryption level")
alable.grid(row=0, column=1)

a = Entry(root)
a.grid(row=1, column=1)


def encryption():
    m,x= e.get(), a.get()  
    encrypted = ''
    for i in range(len(m)):
        if m[i] == ' ':
            encrypted += ' '
        for q in range(len(alphabit)):
            if m[i] == alphabit[q]:
                encrypted += alphabit[q]
    if len(encrypted) == len(m):
        print(encrypted)
        blable = Label(root, text=encrypted)
        blable.grid(row=3, column=0)


button = tk.Button(root, text='encrypt', command=encryption)
button.grid(row=2, column=1)
root.mainloop()
```